# Securing an Ubuntu Lucid web server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04, internet-security

I have an Ubuntu Lucid server that is public facing. I haven't really configured much on it except installing SSH (sshd) and Apache (httpd); I don't have a firewall or anything. Are there some common rules that I should follow to secure my system? I've been following [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/apache-hardening/) on securing my Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPTables will get you fairly secure:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo